# Menu Not Working For Mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, drop-down-menu

My site is finally how I want it to look - however no menu for mobile? I even installed the template fresh and when I look via mobile there is no menu. Is it possible to fix this or do I need to search for a new template?

The site is http://welshmediation.com/.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="santa barbara mediator">
    <meta name="Jennie Walsh Mediation" content="">

    <title>Jennie K. Welsh Mediation</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="/css/small-business.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <style type="text/css">
    .auto-style1 {
        font-size: large;
    }
    .auto-style3 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: large;
    }
    .auto-style5 {
        font-size: medium;
    }
    .auto-style13 {
        font-size: large;
        color: #F17411;
    }
    .auto-style17 {
        width: 1170px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
    }
    .auto-style18 {
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .auto-style19 {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Regular", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    text-align: center;
}
    .auto-style20 {
    width: 1170px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-size: small;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Regular", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<body style="background-color: #Fcfad3">

    <div>

    <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="background-color: #848482; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; height: 80px; ">
        <div class="auto-style17">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="auto-style18">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <div>
                    &nbsp;</div>
                </a></div>
            <div style="height: 50px">
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://welshmediation.com/">
                        <span class="auto-style13">HOME</span></a>
                    </li>
<li>
                        <a href="http://welshmediation.com/whymediation.html">
                        <span class="auto-style13">WHY MEDIATE?</span></a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="http://welshmediation.com/howiwork.html">
                        <span class="auto-style13">HOW I WORK</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://welshmediation.com/services.html">
                        <span class="auto-style13">MEDIATION SERVICES</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://welshmediation.com/about.html">
                        <span class="auto-style13">ABOUT</span></a>
                    </li>

                     <li>
                        <a href="http://welshmediation.com/helpful.html">
                        <span class="auto-style13">HELPFUL RESOURCES</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    </div>
```

Comment: You also have two opening <body> tags there, though I doubt that is preventing the js you haven't included like the first reply says.

Comment: I could not find a second body tag but thank you!

Comment: `<body>
<body style="background-color: #Fcfad3">`

Answer (score 1):

You have not include jquery js file and bootstrap js file that's why it is not run as you accept
please include and then try it.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

You should update your CSS like this in `@media screen and (min-width:0) and (max-width:479px){}` for mobile.

`<div>` above class `"bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"` should `style="height: 50px; width: 25%;"`

```
.navbar-fixed-top .nav {
    background: #000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px 0;
    width: auto;
}
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse, .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse
{
    float: left;
    max-height: 340px;
}
```

Comment: Rohit thank you so much!  I can now see the menu on mobile!  However its sort of on top of the page content rather than in the menu bar at the top?